# Examples of partial adjoints

Tags: ct.category-theory, teaching

Recall that a functor $$R: D \to C$$ is said to have a partial left adjoint $L$ defined at an object $X \in C$ if the functor

$$D \to Sets, Y \mapsto Hom_C(X, R(Y))$$

is corepresentable by some object $L(X)$.

Since adjoints in category theory are enormously widespread, I would like to ask: **what are useful / noteworthy examples, mainly from the perspective of teaching, of ''partial'' adjoints?**

Examples I can find so far are:

- limits being a partial right adjoint of the diagonal functor, which may not be a right adjoint unless all limits exist,
- the discrete-topology functor $Sets \to Top$ admits a partial left adjoint given by connected components $\pi_0$, defined on locally connected spaces.

Comment: Similarly, right kan extensions to $C$ along a functor $f:A \to B$ are a partial right adjoint to the restriction functor $[B,C] \to [A,C]$, which may not be an adjoint unless all right Kan extensions exist.